# Leveled - Terms foreach

Tags: terms

I need to build a php foreach that goes through all my terms in my custom taxonomy 'Section'.

I know how to get a foreach of all the terms in 'Section', but what i cant do is build it with levels.

I want the top parent term to be the heading, and its children will be displayed in a list.

Heres an html example of the output i need.

```
<div class="accordian">
   <div> Term Parent </div>
   <ul>
      <li> Term Child </li>
      <li> Term Child </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="accordian">
   <div> Term Parent </div>
   <ul>
      <li> Term Child </li>
      <li> Term Child </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your foreach loop, so we can alter it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a hierarchical terms list ?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14652/how-to-show-a-hierarchical-terms-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work on it a little more and built the answer myself. Heres the code i needed.

```
<?php
    $parent_terms = get_terms('section', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0&parent=0');
    foreach ( $parent_terms as $parent_term ) { ?>

    <div class="accordian open">
        <div class="accordian-title module-gradient"><?php echo $parent_term->name; ?></div>
        <?php 
            $get_parent = get_term_by('name', $parent_term->name, 'section');
            $parent_id = $get_parent->term_id;
            $child_terms = get_terms('section', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0&parent='.$parent_id);

            if ( count($child_terms) > 0 ) { ?>

            <div class="accordian-menu">
                <?php foreach ( $child_terms as $child_term ) { ?>
                    <div class="accordian-item">
                       <?php echo $child_term->name; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `wp_list_categories( 'taxonomy=section' )` ? It'll do all the nesting & hard work for you!

If you want more control over the HTML output, implement a [custom walker](http://scribu.net/wordpress/extending-the-category-walker.html).