# Taxonomies: display hierarchical parent list

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

I've been using WP for years, but this is my first time with taxonomies, so I need a little bit of help.

Like in the question [How to show a hierarchical terms list?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14652/how-to-show-a-hierarchical-terms-list) I have a taxonomy called `places`, which contains a hierarchical list of places (first level for countries, second level for cities, etc...).

A post can have an associated place: for example, we could take Berlin (child of Germany, child of Europe).

Now, the output I want is something like this:

Where: [Berlin](http://www.site.com/places/berlin), [Germany](http://www.site.com/places/germany), [Europe](http://www.site.com/places/europe).

I've tried some solutions, but none works. I'm pretty sure that there must be a simple and clean solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_get_object_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) will give you the term assigned to the post, you could then use [`get_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) to get an array of the parent's IDs, then [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) ID to get the names and slugs.